# MacVim not downloading ./vim file?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

Im trying to download plugins for my macVim but there is no ./Vim folder? when I download macvim all I get is the application file which works.....am I downloading it from the wrong place?

Comment: Manually create the `.vim` folder `.vimrc` file in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal.app, run the following commands to create the `~/.vim` directory and the `~/.vimrc` file.

```
$ cd
$ touch .vimrc
$ mkdir .vim
$ open .vim
```

Comment: on the mac and for MacVim, you will need to put your plugins in the ~/.vim/added directory, or in your case ~/.Vim/added

Comment: @Deesbek, no, first it's `~/.vim`, second there's no such thing as a `~/.vim/added` directory. I wonder where you got that idea.

Comment: I agree of course it is ~/.vim however on a mac ~/.Vim will also work as stated in the other answer (it is a bad idea to use it though), and depending on your set up you can put your plugins in /added and they will work. I am not sure why you say there is no such thing as ~/.vim/added, if you create it and reference it, of course there is such a thing. That being said, I am happy to delete my comment if you think I should.

Comment: @Deesbek, well, you could "reference" (did you mean "add to your `runtimepath`"?) `foo` too but there's no reason to do so, same for `added`. One can do crazy things with his setup but it would be a mistake to validate that. `.vim` is the canonical name for that directory and there's no reason whatsoever to give it another name. Similarly, moving a plugin in `added` won't work because it is not a standard directory: you need some work to make Vim source plugins found in that directory. Without proper explanations, saying "put your plugins in the `~/.vim/added` directory" is *very* misleading.

Comment: And I guess that is how one learns, you say something stupid and you get slapped down.  Thanks, I will be modifying my vim set up.

Comment: I got slapped down a lot in the beginning, and I still do but less. Yes, I think that's how I learn. And teach.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.vim` (case sensitive!) you mean? If it dose not exist, just create it.

Comment: osx's file system is case insensitive so it might work even with the capitalized V (Although not recommended)

Comment: `Journaled HFS+`(default filesystem) is case-insensitive, but `Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+` is case-sensitive. Anyway, use the directory `.Vim` folder instead `.vim` a bad idea.